# Sphinx PDF output: Apostrophes in python source are replaced by right single quotes

Tags: python, pdf, latex, python-sphinx

I am outputting some [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/tiktuk/plac-tik-branch/src/191c050cfee0/plac/doc/) as PDF using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org). It's all very fine except for when python source code are output, then single quotes (unicode U+0027) are output as right single quotes (U+2019) which look awkward.

[Here](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) are images of the glyphs in question and [here](http://placdocs.tiktuk.net/plac.pdf) is my generated PDF.

Does anybody know how to correct this?

Comment: This question isn't self-contained; it points to examples on external sites, which are subject to change. For example, looking at the "generated pdf", one isn't able to quickly identify the described problem. Maybe it's fixed? If so, how does seeing the fixed example help future users understand whether the question is relevant to their situation? I know it's old, but if you can [edit] the question to clarify the problem, that would make it a better resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your sphinx `conf.py` (or append to [latex_preamble](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-latex_preamble) if it is already set):

```
latex_preamble = """
\usepackage{upquote}
"""
```